# How do you do sumproduct in PHP?

Tags: php, sumproduct

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.72 | 97.29 |
| 2 | 0.72 | 67.68 |
| 3 | 0.72 | 66.97 |
| 4 | 0.72 | 67.57 |
| 5 | 0.72 | 67.80 |
| 6 | 0.72 | 94.71 |
| 7 | 0.72 | 136.23 |
| 8 | 0.72 | 146.77 |
| 9 | 0.72 | 139.06 |
| 10 | 0.72 | 95.39 |
| 11 | 0.35 | 58.66 |
| 12 | 0.20 | 48.90 |
| 13 | 0.05 | 37.07 |
| 14 | 0.05 | 61.31 |
| 15 | 0.20 | 95.26 |
| 16 | 0.35 | 140.80 |
| 17 | 0.72 | 228.09 |
| 18 | 0.72 | 318.25 |
| 19 | 0.72 | 407.95 |
| 20 | 0.72 | 413.11 |
| 21 | 0.72 | 409.11 |
| 22 | 0.72 | 394.49 |
| 23 | 0.72 | 300.57 |
| 24 | 0.72 | 162.24 |

I need to work out this spreadsheet formula `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A24,B1:B24)` in PHP.

This is what I tried (but I think my formula is incorrect)

```
$a = array( 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.35, 0.20, 0.05, 0.05, 0.20, 0.35, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72 );
$b = array( 97.29, 67.68, 66.97, 67.57, 67.80, 94.71, 136.23, 146.77, 139.06, 95.39, 58.66, 48.90, 37.07, 61.31, 95.26, 140.80, 228.09, 318.25, 407.95, 413.11, 409.11, 394.49, 300.57, 162.24 );

$a_total = 0;
$b_total = 0;

foreach( $a as $row ) {
    $a_total += $row;
}
foreach( $b as $row ) {
    $b_total += $row;
}

$sumproduct = $a_total * $b_total;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding all the rows in each range and multiplying the result. That's not what SUMPRODUCT does.

You should be multiplying the corresponding elements from each array and totalling the results:

```
$a = array( 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.35, 0.20, 0.05, 0.05, 0.20, 0.35, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72 );
$b = array( 97.29, 67.68, 66.97, 67.57, 67.80, 94.71, 136.23, 146.77, 139.06, 95.39, 58.66, 48.90, 37.07, 61.31, 95.26, 140.80, 228.09, 318.25, 407.95, 413.11, 409.11, 394.49, 300.57, 162.24 );

$sumProduct = 0;

for( $i = 0; $i<count($a); $i++ ) {
    $sumProduct += ($a[$i]*$b[$i]);
}

echo $sumProduct;
```

See https://3v4l.org/hkFhf

Of course, this is just one of the options for SUMPRODUCT. See the [Microsoft docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) for more options for SUMPRODUCT